# SQL: two many to many joins with one match in each

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My data model:

- Profile has many Projects (Project.ProfileID)
- Projects many-many Speciality (Projects_Specialities table [ProjectID/SpecialityID])
- Projects many-many Industry (Projects_Industries table [ProjectID/IndustryID])

When given an IndustryID and a SpecialityID, I need to get all the Profiles that have at least one project with that IndustryID and at least one project with that SpecialityID.

I've tried a million different things that I could post here, but I figured I would see if anyone had an obvious answer first.

Comment: Can you post your attempt's code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the joined tables by profile and filter for the groups of interest:

```
SELECT   Project.ProfileID
FROM     Project
    JOIN Projects_Specialities USING (ProjectID)
    JOIN Projects_Industries   USING (ProjectID)
WHERE    Projects_Specialities.SpecialityID = ?
     AND Projects_Industries.IndustryID     = ?
GROUP BY Project.ProfileID
HAVING   SUM(Projects_Specialities.SpecialityID = ?)
     AND SUM(Projects_Industries.IndustryID     = ?)
```

The `WHERE` clause is not necessary for correctness, but will add a performance benefit (especially if an index can be used for lookups).

Comment: This has a lot of promise. Will test it in the morning. Did not even think of doing a SUM() on an expression like that!

Comment: Total lifesaver. Thank you!